# SGE : Parallel Environment for a multithreaded java code

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, sungridengine

I have written a multi threaded java code, which when runs creates 8 threads and the computation continues on these threads. I would like to submit this job to a SGE cluster but I am not sure which parallel environment (`pe`) should I choose? or should I create one? I am new to SGE. The simple way would be to run it in serial mode, but that's inefficient.

Regarding creating a `pe`, where does it need to be created? Should the SGE deamon also need to have this `pe` ? When I submitted a job with some random name as `pe`, I got

```
 job rejected: the requested parallel environment "openmpi" does not exist
```

Comment: The parallel environments that a Grid Engine installation offers are (very) installation specific.  You should ask your sys-admins this question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I'll ask the admin, but still what kind of pe, would suit best to a multi-threaded java code? Though I might not be able to get it as its installation specific.

Comment: You need a PE with an `allocation_rule` of `$pe_slots` and `job_is_first_task` of `TRUE`. This is not a programming question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threaded applications must get all their slots on a single node. That's why you need a Parallel Environment with `allocation_rule` set to `$pe_slots`. Parallel environments are configured by the SGE administrator using the `qconf -ap PE_name`. As a user you can only get the list of the available PEs using `qconf -spl` and can query the configuration of a particular PE using `qconf -sp PE_name`. You can walk all PEs and see their allocation rules with the following `(ba)sh` script:

```sh
for pe_name in `qconf -spl`; do
  echo $pe_name
  qconf -sp $pe_name | grep allocation_rule
done
```

But you should already be talking to your SGE admin instead of trying to justify your off-topic question here.